# Angular JS make value lower and check condition

Tags: angularjs

I have value that might be upppercase or lowercase. I want to convert that to lower and compare and if that condition satisfies that it should show.

ie

```
<div ng-if="test = 'Xyz'">show message</div>
```

In this case  test is my model variable and its Xyz is the text. it can be XYZ or xyZ.

so I want every condition should satisfy.

Xyz value is fixed . it either XYZ,xYZ or XYZ all there conditions should be satisfy.

How it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. i did by

```
<div ng-if="test.toLowerCase() == xyz">show message</div>
```

And it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

call a function from `ng-if` and return the lower case text from that function

```
<div ng-if="test == lower('Xyz')">show message</div>

$scope.lower = function(text){
 return text.toLowerCase()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for it but my scenario is diffrence so i did by

<div ng-if="test.toLowerCase() == xyz">show message</div>

And it works for me